# 'pyglet.graphics' has no attribute 'vertex_list'

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm trying to make a Triangle with pyglet but I keep seeing this error.

```
AttributeError: module 'pyglet.graphics' has no attribute 'vertex_list'
```

I am not sure what is the problem exactly.

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
from pyglet.gl import *


class Triangle:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.vertices = pyglet.graphics.vertex_list(3, ('v3f', [-0.5,-0.5,0.0, 0.5,-0.5,0.0, 0.0,0.5,0.0]),
                                                       ('c3B', [100,200,220, 200,110,100, 100,250,100]))

class MyWindow(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_minimum_size(400,300)

        self.triangle = Triangle()

    def on_draw(self):
        self.triangle.vertices.draw(GL_TRIANGLES)

    def on_resize(self, width, height):
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    
if __name__ =="__main__":
    window = MyWindow(1280, 720, "Hello", resizable=True)
    window.on_draw()
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Looking at https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/graphics/index.html, I don't see any function `vertex_list`, so what makes you think it exists?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check which version of pyglet you are using. Recently (on 01.11.2022) pyglet version 2.0 got released which changed how to use vertex based drawing majorly.

`pyglet.graphics.vertex_list` was used in earlier versions of pyglet (for information how to use this refer to https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.5-maintenance/modules/graphics/index.html which is the documentation for pyglet version 1.5-maintenance). If you want to work with this older version make sure to use **pyglet version 1.5.27** or lower

In **pyglet version 2.0** you have to create a Shader Program and use this to draw vertex based graphics. For more information about this refer to pyglets documentation regarding *Shaders and Rendering*: https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/graphics.html